# How to clear console in gdb while in TUI

Tags: linux, console, gdb

While i am debugging my code in `GDB` in `TUI` mode `Control + L` wont work to clear console. So how am i able to clear console while i am in `TUI` mode? It just refreshes the screen but doesnt clear the console. I looked at the GDB's official website but as i said, there is only `Control + L`, but that only clears console while **not** in TUI mode.

The website is here: https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/TUI-Keys.html#TUI-Keys

Comment: I've always wanted to know this as well and I'm pretty sure there's no direct way to do this (which is ridiculous imo).

Answer (score 1):

The following works, but is a bit of a cheat:

```
control x-a
control L
control x-a
```

i.e. get out of TUI, clear console, and get back in.

Perhaps you'll have better luck, but I thought 'shell clear' or 'shell reset' might work while in a TUI session, but both (esp. reset) confused the curses state significantly.

Comment: Hi, with gdb 11.2 this does not work for me. It clears the terminal but when I return to the TUI all the previous commands are still there